# proxychains-ng with nmap issues

Tags: penetration-test, nmap, proxychains

Can anyone tell me if proxychains-ng has limitations to work with nmap? I found that it does not work well when using -sV option in nmap. (stop at "Initiating NSE at ..." and never finish the scan) Does anyone have a solution to this issue? By the way, I am using socks4 server for proxychains and default configuration file.(only changed local port).

Thanks.

Comment: I have used nmap in privileged mode with -- https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng/ -- and had zero issues, including with version detection. If I were to take a guess, it sounds like a bad proxychains.conf file

Comment: Could you tell me how you configured your proxychains.conf file? I just used default configuration. Or could you recommend any helpful materials for me to read?

Comment: I had almost exactly this -- https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng/blob/master/src/proxychains.conf -- except the last line. I had "http proxyservername 8080 username passwordsecret" instead of "socks4 127.0.0.1 9050"

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of any problems with the use of proxychains-ng and Nmap, but to be sure that Nmap is not trying to do any raw socket or packet capture operations that are incompatible with proxychains-ng, you should use the `--unprivileged` option. Additionally, since version 6.40, Nmap has supported proxies natively with the `--proxies` option, which covers the `-sV` option and NSE scripts, but **not the host discovery, port scan, OS scan, or traceroute functions.**